# Regarding AsyncTask for creating a loading screen

Tags: android

I am on a dilemma on how to achieve "Creating a loading screen" on a AsyncTask mainly using progressDialog.

What I am doing is that I have a method which takes no inputs and just shows a textview.

> private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask {

So what my method does is simply like 1 + 1 = 2 but in a more complex way of storing a giganormous string which then get shown on a textview.

So my question is how do I achieve the result of a progress dialog before this long load?

Comment: The description is very unclear, if the answers provided below do not really answer your question - then you should redesign your question, maybe providing some code snippets to help us understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private progressDialog pd;
public void runMethod(){
new doStuuff.execute();
}


private Class doStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
//Everything in your code except for anything that is xml or relates with any view. Mostly calculations
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Your main background view code ends up falling here
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Your optional view and where it starts
pd = ProgressDialog.show(View_Book_As_Whole.this, "Loading", "Please wait...");
        }

}
```

I was being too noob not to understand the concept but it is relatively easy once you understand it. onPreExecute() means that it runs before anything  and it takes priority first then goes to doInBackground(), and then onPostExecute() it runs the final task. This all works in the background of the UI.

Answer (score 4):

Android already has a [progress dialog class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) built-in.  I'd recommend using that, unless there's something about it that doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: What I wanted was to be able to show progress dialog first when activity loads. However it keeps showing at the same time as the actual event the entire thing loads.